# Rails paperclip params not being sent when updating user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I am installed paperclip, but no params are being sent. Here is what I have...

```
#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user, :url => users_path, :html => { :multipart => true } do |form| %>
  <%= form.file_field :avatar %>
<% end %>

#app/models/user.rb
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" },
                    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"

app/controllers/users_controller.rb
  def update
    @user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
     ...
```

Any ideas? Not sure where to go next. I don't even see 'avatar' in my params hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add the code...

```
  <%= f.file_field :avatar %>
```

to my app/views/users/_form.html.erb file rather than app/views/users/edit.html.erb

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. Thanks for posting a reply answer so other users can get some visibility!

Answer (score 1):

At a glance the code you have there looks OK. Can you paste in the request Logs located in the console, or `logs/development.log`. It should help give some insight to the issue.

I wrote an article [Uploading Files to S3 in Ruby with Paperclip](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/paperclip-s3) on the Heroku dev center. The repo has example code on how to set up Paperclip. Might help to reference that?

Comment: Yah...here ya go http://pastie.org/8545734. I gots nothing! I rolled my own authentication, so I'm wondering if I am missing something in my update param. Here is that http://pastie.org/8545740.

Comment: The auth system shouldn't make any difference. I noticed in the logs that there is a field for "icon" that is coming through empty. Above you reference "avatar." Is this intentional or should those be the same field?

Comment: Good article harlow, that will come in handy. The icon field is just a dummy field I had set up. I am using avatar as outlined in the documentation. I figured out my issue, an am documenting below.